# BigQuery returns "Unparseable query parameter `` in type `TYPE_INT64`" when the query projects a literal that is a parameter of a prepared statement

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, prepared-statement

BigQuery returns the error ``` Unparseable query parameter `` in type ``TYPE_INT64``" ``` when executing a query that meets all these conditions:

- I run the query as a prepared statement.
- The query has a literal of type String in the `SELECT`.
- The value of this literal is passed as a parameter. For example `SELECT ? AS field_1...`.

For example, this code:

```java
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TestBigQueryPreparedStatement {

    private static final String CONNECTION_URI =
                    "jdbc:bigquery://<connection_uri>";

    private static final String QUERY = "SELECT ? AS `_SOURCE_TABLE`, field1 FROM test_view";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        Class.forName("com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.Driver");
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URI)) {
            try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY)) {

                // The problem also occurs if I replace this line with "ps.setObject(...)
                ps.setString(1, "SOURCE_TABLE");
                try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getInt(2));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Produces this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: Unparseable query parameter `` in type `TYPE_INT64`, Bad int64 value: SOURCE_TABLE value: 'SOURCE_TABLE'
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.requests.jobs.JobsInsertRequest.throwException(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.requests.AbstractRequestWithRetry.executeWithRetry(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.queryclient.JobsInsertClient.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQAbstractExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQSQLExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeWithParams(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at TestBigQueryPreparedStatement.main(TestBigQueryPreparedStatement.java:20)
Caused by: com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.exceptions.JobExecutionErrorException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: Unparseable query parameter `` in type `TYPE_INT64`, Bad int64 value: SOURCE_TABLE value: 'SOURCE_TABLE'
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unparseable query parameter `` in type `TYPE_INT64`, Bad int64 value: SOURCE_TABLE value: 'SOURCE_TABLE'
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.requests.jobs.JobsInsertRequest.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.requests.jobs.JobsInsertRequest.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
```

- Reproducible with the latest JDBC driver of BigQuery (Simba v1.3.0 1001).
- This error also occurs with `PreparedStatement.setDate(...)` and `setFloat(...)` but works fine with `setDecimal(...)`, `setInt(...)` (I have not checked the output with all the setXXX methods of `PreparedStatement`)

Is it possible to execute in BigQuery queries that have a literal in the `SELECT` and to execute the query as a prepared statement?

This is a sample scenario. My application has an execution engine that runs SQL queries on any database and it always does so with prepared statements. Occasionally, the query will have a literal in the `SELECT` and with BigQuery, I get this error above (it works with any other database). I can do certain changes specifically for the query generator of BigQuery but it would be very difficult to change the code so the literals in the `SELECT` clause are passed as literals, not parameters of the prepared statement.

Comment: Hello, By literal did you meant Named parameters ?  If it is the case can you check this article? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#java. Also for troubleshooting have you tried downgrading the jdbc driver?

Comment: Hello, or this one: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-params-positional#bigquery_query_params_positional-java

Comment: @NestorCenizaJr and Samuel I am using the classes of the JDBC API, the links you mention refer to proprietary classes of BigQuery. I need to keep using the standard methods of the JDBC API as I do when running queries in other databases.

Comment: Regarding literals, I mean a fixed value - not a column of the table I query.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use positional query parameters in the `select` or `from` part of the query. Positional parameters can only occur in the `where` clause of the query.

```
        SELECT word, word_count
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
        WHERE corpus = ?
        AND word_count >= ?
        ORDER BY word_count DESC;";
```

See also https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-params-positional